# What does it mean when the cumtimes of callees don't add up to the total cumtime of a function?

Tags: python, performance

I'm using `cProfile.Profile`.

In the output of `print_callees`, I can see that a function takes about 2 seconds of `cumtime`.

But when I check the output of the functions it calls, their `cumtime` don't sum up to that of the caller. Actually it's much smaller.

What could be the reason of this?

Comment: I’m assuming that the parent function does also do things other than just calling those child functions. So of course that adds to the cumulative time. That being said, you should probably provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

That actually makes a lot of sense: the difference is the time the code in the function, excluding the calls it makes, takes. For example:

```
def foo():
    for i in range(99999):
        print 'hello'
    bar()
    baz()
```

The cumulative time of `foo` will be much larger than the sums of times of `bar()` and `baz` - it has to do the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the function performs computations (and most probably contains a loop).

Example:

```
def foo(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(n):
        s += i
    print(s)
    return s
```

`print()` is a called by `foo()`, but for a large enough `n` more time is spent in the `for` loop (and thus in `foo()` proper) than in `print()`. Thus `cumtime` of `foo()` should significantly exceed `cumtime` of `print()`.